# What exactly is required to use an external object in a GWT web application

Tags: java, gwt, gwt-rpc

The actual code is on a server that doesn't have internet access so I am going to use pseudocode here to try to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a project called MyCoolHMI
Contained within it is a GWT website with multiple client/server/shared sub packages
For this example I am working in MyCoolHMI /com/src/foods/cookies/client/ShowCookieList.java

I have another project in the same workspace called IGotYerCookies which contains among other things a database DAO/DTO that allow access to a the_best_cookies table.  The dao and dto are called com.src.gotyercookies.database.TheBestCookiesDAO.java and com.src.gotyercookies.database.TheBestCookiesDTO.java
I need to call TheBestCookiesDAO.getBestCookie() which returns List containing the top 3 cookies from ShowCookieList.java.

What exactly do I need to do in order for (other than class path stuff) ShowCookieList.java to use TheBestCookiesDAO and TheBestCookiesDTO?.

I have written Service and ServiceAsync classes and placed them in MyCoolHMI /com/src/foods/cookies/shared for a DAO and a DTO.
I have also written ServiceAsyncImpl for the DAO and DTO and put them in the same directory with TheBestCookiesDAO/DTO in IGotYerCookies.

I can't wrap my brain around how to handle the DTO when it comes back from the callback, or how to set arrange the actual call to get one back..

In the end server is where the Impl class had to go and shared is where the Service and ServiceAsync ended up.  Then I had to put an entry in the web.xml file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to use these classes on client side. Simplest solution is to use GWT RPC to access those objects. Read this page http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC.html about how to use GWT RPC.

This how you can access it on client side

```
BestCookiesServiceAsync service = (BestCookiesServiceAsync) GWT.create(BestCookiesService.class);
```

BestCookiesService interface in client part

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("BestCookiesService")
public interface BestCookiesService extends RemoteService {

   // methods
   // Cookie should implement IsSerializable
   Cookie[] getBestCookies(); 

}
```

BestCookiesServiceAsync interface (copy of previous but with AsyncCallbacks)

```
public interface BestCookiesServiceAsync {

    // same methods but with callbacks
}
```

BestCookiesServiceImpl class. It is implementation of the first interface on server side.

```
public class BestCookiesServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements BestCookiesService {

    // you can access your DAOs here
    @Override
    public Cookie[] getBestCookies() {
         BestCookiesDAO dao = getBestCookiesDAO();
         BestCookiesList list = dao.getBestCookies();

         Cookie[] array = new Cookie[list.size()];
         for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
             array[i] = new Cookie(list.get(i).getIngredients());
         }

         return array;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, that's what I am looking for.. I guess, how to set up a RPC (even though java only has methods, we call it a procedure call..grrrr) that will see the external objects.  I'm going to add a bit more detail ..

Comment: What is the return type of the call to getBestCookie from inside ShowCookieList, it returns a list of DTOs which contain ingredients and names of the top 3 cookies.  So from inside the ShowCookieList object how do I get that list of DTOs out and access their methods to display names and ingredients contained within?

Comment: In your BestCookiesService, if I put a method that is TheBestCookiesDTO getBestCookies() it errors out saying it can't find the entry point for TheBestCookiesDTO.

Comment: It is better to create some Cookie class inside your client package with fields you need on the client side. You can do it in BestCookiesServiceImpl because you have access to DAOs and DTOs there.

Comment: Where do I put BestCookiesServiceImpl, I put it in the MyCoolHMI /com/src/foods/cookies/server area but it can't access BestCookiesService to implement, it can be seen but the GWT compiler can't see it...  BestCookiesService is in the MyCoolHMI /com/src/foods/cookies/client .. should it be in shared?

Comment: When you say on the client part, or on the server side.. you really mean in the package called client or the package called server right?  When I try to implement BestCookiesService in the BestCookiesServiceImpl that is located in the server package the GWT compiler says client.BestCookieService doesn't exist.

Comment: Client part is that you will have running in the browser (commonly "client" package). Server part means that you will have running on java server ("server" package). Service interface should be available both to client and server code but implementation only for server. You will need to setup implementation as servlet inside web.xml. If you have them in different projects (for Eclipse) or modules (for IntelliJ) server project/module have to reference client to get access for service interface and model classes (like Cookie).